# How can I get the data-value attribute as a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<button type="button" data-value="100" id="btn">BUTTON</button>

const btnVal = $("#btn").data("value");
console.log(typeof btnVal); -- "btnVal" type is number
```

I want to get the value as a string, but is there any other way to use toString()?

Comment: I don't see the problem in using `toString()` but you could add `""+` before your jquery selector.

Comment: The btnVal returned as string only. You can use it as string wherever you want. or else you can define a string variable and assign this value to that variable. However javascript variable datatype is adaptive.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Whether it is "toString()" or " ""+ ", after getting the data-value in the end, it must be processed separately.

Comment: @SachinVishwakarma

I thought that if I did the above, it would be returned as a string, but it actually contained a numeric value. So I was wondering if I need to do a separate operation like toString() .

Comment: `.attr(name)` is *always* a string while `.data(name)` will infer the type based on the value.

Comment: @freedomn-m

Yes. I have confirmed that the type is determined according to your description. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read it as an attribute. like this:

```js
const btnVal = $("#btn").attr("data-value");
console.log(typeof btnVal);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-value="100" id="btn">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When the value is imported as "attr", it is confirmed that it is recognized as a string by default.

Comment: **NB** reading using `.attr(name)` and *writing* with `.data(name, val)` are *not compatible* - take care when using `.attr("data-...`